# Kafka Message Corruption

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are on confluent platform 3.2.2 (kafka 0.10.2.1-2). We are seeing a large number of Corrupt messages in the logs very frequently. We recently upgraded from 0.8.2 and the frequency of corrupt messages have shot up.

We have tried with two different consumers so can confirm that this is indeed a corrupt message. Further, we are observing this a lot more on log compacted topics.

Is there something know to be wrong with this version of Kafka. Is there any configuration for our Kafka that could be causing such an issue.

Comment: I am using kafka_2.12-1.0.1 and It is perfectly working fine.

Comment: That's a pretty stable version. What is the nature of the corruption? Missing pieces of records? Compression gone wrong? Spread across all replicas for a partition or local? Lots of potential factors here that might not be related to Kafka based on the description.

Comment: @Goutam This question isn't asking about a Kafka version that was just released

Comment: They are missing pieces of the record. I don't think its a compression issue as most of these topics are uncompressed.